# open-liberty : cannot configure jmsActivationSpec

Tags: jms, open-liberty

I have the following configs in my IBM Liberty `server.xml`:

```
<!-- resource adapter location -->
<variable name="wmqJmsClient.rar.location" value="${shared.resource.dir}/lib/global/wmq.jmsra-9.1.0.0.rar"/>

<!-- jmsActivationSpec configs -->
<jmsActivationSpec authDataRef="myAuthData" id="my-app-name/MyMessageDrivenBean">
        <properties.wmqJms destinationRef="jms/MyQueue"
                           destinationType="javax.jms.Queue"
                           sslCipherSuite="SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256"
                           channel="MY.MQCHANNEL"
                           queueManager="MY_QM"
                           hostName="myhost" port="32100"
                           transportType="CLIENT" />
</jmsActivationSpec>
```

I also have a message-driven bean I am using to handle messages that appear on the queue. And everything works fine.

I'd like to migrate to [open-liberty](https://openliberty.io/) and keep my JMS stuff but their documentation is a little bit different even though the same config elements are there.

Some properties are missing and it's not clear how to replace them. No `hostName` and `port`, instead I found only `remoteServerAddress` and it has to be a triplet `host:port:something_i_dont_understand` so not sure it's exactly the same :)

How can I configure all this required stuff in open-liberty to make my message-driven bean work?

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WebSphere Liberty you are likely using the `wmqJmsClient-2.0` feature. This isn't available in Open Liberty, but it is really only a convenience feature. You should be able to configure the following:

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>jms-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jca-1.7</feature>
</featureManager>

<resourceAdapter id="mqJMS" location="${shared.resource.dir}/lib/global/wmq.jmsra-9.1.0.0.rar"/>

<!-- jmsActivationSpec configs -->
<jmsActivationSpec authDataRef="myAuthData" id="my-app-name/MyMessageDrivenBean">
    <properties.mqJms destinationRef="jms/MyQueue"
                      destinationType="javax.jms.Queue"
                      sslCipherSuite="SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256"
                      channel="MY.MQCHANNEL"
                      queueManager="MY_QM"
                      hostName="myhost" port="32100"
                      transportType="CLIENT" />
</jmsActivationSpec>
```

This configures the `jms-2.0` feature, and the `jca-1.7` which enables the JMS, and RA support in Liberty. The `resourceAdapter` element configures Liberty to know about the RA's existence and where it is (similar to the variable you have in your existing configuration). The value of the id attribute is then used on the properties element under the `jmsActivationSpec` element, so in the `wmqJmsClient-2.0` feature we define this to be `wmqJms`, in this case I've used `mqJms` because I think `wmqJms` is reserved. In any case this config should work both in Open Liberty and WebSphere Liberty.