# WebSphere to OpenLiberty EJB 3 message driven beans migration from ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi issue

Tags: java, websphere, ejb, open-liberty, message-driven-bean

During the deployment of our migrated ear with 2 war's from old Websphere 8.x into OpenLiberty I get this issue regarding unexpected element in the xmi:

```
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0002E: An exception occurred while starting the application NAMEOFEAR-1.0.0. The exception message was: com.ibm.ws.container.service.metadata.MetaDataException: com.ibm.wsspi.adaptable.module.UnableToAdaptException: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBConfigurationException: com.ibm.wsspi.adaptable.module.UnableToAdaptException: com.ibm.ws.javaee.ddmodel.DDParser$ParseException: CWWKC2256E: Unexpected attribute listenerInputPortName encountered parsing element ejbBindings in the NAMEOFEAR-1.0.0.ear : NAMEOFJAR-1.0.0.jar : META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi deployment descriptor on line 4.
```

Simply removing the listenerInputPortName attribute worked, but I'm sure it will lead to problems afterwards?

The ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejbbnd:EJBJarBinding xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:ejb="ejb.xmi" xmlns:ejbbnd="ejbbnd.xmi" xmi:id="EJBJarBinding_1">
  <ejbJar href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#ejb-jar_ID"/>
  <ejbBindings xmi:type="ejbbnd:MessageDrivenBeanBinding" xmi:id="MessageDrivenBeanBinding_1" listenerInputPortName="SMTPMessageListenerPort">
    <enterpriseBean xmi:type="ejb:MessageDriven" href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#MessageDriven_1"/>
    <resRefBindings xmi:id="ResourceRefBinding_1" jndiName="mail/SMTPMailSession">
  </ejbBindings>
</ejbbnd:EJBJarBinding>
```

Also example ejb-jar.xml:

```
<ejb-jar ...>
    <display-name>ejb</display-name>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <message-driven id="MessageDriven_1">
            <ejb-name>SMTPSender</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.smtp.SMTPSendBean</ejb-class>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
            <message-destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</message-destination-type>
            <activation-config>
              ...
            </activation-config>
            <resource-ref id="ResourceRef_1">
              ...
            </resource-ref>
        </message-driven>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

JMS-resources.xml (I'm using config-drop ins):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server>
 ...


    <jmsQueueConnectionFactory jndiName="jms/CompanySMTPMessageConnectionFactory">
        <properties.mqJMS
                ...
                transportType="CLIENT"/>
    </jmsQueueConnectionFactory>

    <jmsQueue jndiName="jms/SMTPMessageQueue">
        <properties.mqJMS baseQueueName="Q2"/>
    </jmsQueue>
</server>
```

I'm not sure how to migrate it to work with EJB 3.1 and running/deploying in OpenLiberty.

Comment: Provide info to what JMS provider are you trying to connect.

Answer (score 0):

There are no `listener port`s in OpenLiberty. MDBs are using `ActiveSpecifications`.  You have to do update bindings to use AS or do it in  `server.xml`. Check docs for using mdbs in OpenLiberty (depending on jms provider you are using) - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=liberty-deploying-message-driven-beans-within

**Update based on your additional info**:
Looking at the resources defined, it seems that you are using WebSphere MQ and want your MDB to connect to the queue (although you didnt provide their names - you will have to check ListenerPorts configurations).
Here are a few changes you need:

- change feature - you should use **jca-1.7** instead of wasJmsClient (check this [open-liberty : cannot configure jmsActivationSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612324/open-liberty-cannot-configure-jmsactivationspec))
- add `<feature>jmsMdb-3.2</feature>`
- add active spec (fix queue/channel/host etc):

```
<!-- jmsActivationSpec configs -->
<jmsActivationSpec id="my-app-name/MyMessageDrivenBean">
    <properties.mqJms destinationRef="jms/MyQueue"
                      destinationType="javax.jms.Queue"
                      channel="DEV.APP.SVRCONN"
                      hostName="${ibm.mq.hostname}"
                      port="1414"
                      queueManager="QM1"
                      transportType="CLIENT" />
</jmsActivationSpec>
```

If your QM requires authentication you need to add these additional props:

```
                      userName="${ibm.mq.username}"
                      password="${ibm.mq.password}"
```

`id` in the activeSpec must follow the following naming convention "application name/module name/bean name" in your case it shoiuld be for exampe `id=NAMEOFEAR-1.0.0/ejb/CompanyEventLog`

You should be able to define this binding also via `xmi` binding file, but I dont have example at hand since its very old. You would need IBM Rational Application Developer, which should still have editor for xmi files.

In `xml` format it would look like this:

```
<ejb-jar-bnd
        xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd_1_1.xsd" 
    (http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd_1_1.xsd%27) version="1.1">
    
    <message-driven name="PriceChangeMDBBean">
            <jca-adapter activation-spec-binding-name="PriceChangeAS" destination-binding-name="jms/TriggerQ" />
    </message-driven>
</ejb-jar-bnd>
```

So maybe try first the binding in `server.xml`.

Comment: If you are using an EE 6 module then I think you still require the xmi formats, even when you are using EE 7+ features.

Comment: Yes, liberty does support use of xmi files for EJB 1.x and 2.x modules. There is no requirement to upgrade your MDBs to EJB 3.x with xml binding files, you just need to remove the use of listener ports and instead use an ActivationSpecification as described in the link provided.

Comment: Ahh, forgot about that xmi support for older modules... Thanks ;-)

Comment: Also, there is a tool for WebSphere 8.5.5 which will migrate a message-driven bean application that uses a listener port to instead use an activationspec.  This converts in place, so it may be helpful to use this tool first on WebSphere before migrating the application to liberty :
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/8.5.5?topic=cjrwmmp-migrating-listener-port-activation-specification-use-websphere-mq-messaging-provider

Comment: @Tracy Isn't OpenLiberty supporting only EJB 3.x and higher? As far as I remember older specs are only supported in WebSphere Liberty, not the OpenLiberty, correct?

Comment: @Gas Generally the Java EE specifications require backward compatibility. While Open Liberty has features for EJB 3.2 and 4.0, and WebSphere Liberty also has EJB 3.1, all of those specification levels require support for the older EJB 2.x APIs and deployment descriptors.  You would configure to use the EJB 3.2 features in Liberty, but can install most EJB 1.x or 2.x applications and they would work without modification.  There are exceptions, such as listener ports, where the newer specifications added activation specs. Entity beans were made optional in EJB 3.x, so not supported in Liberty.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments so far! 
I added the jms resources config xml in the original question. 
Can you please give me an example (in your answer maybe, or new answer) on how to add this AcitveSpecification in the xmls? Im too dumb maybe, I didn't made it to work yet.

Comment: @Deery I added few things to the answer, which should help you a bit, you will still need to double check properties, like queue name, qmgr etc..

Comment: Thanks @Gas ! This looks nice. And the properties/config like channel, queue name, ... I need to retrieve from eg. ListenerPorts configurations ? Will I find those in the old WebSphere Application Server? 
Thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: Also: Do I need to edit something in my ejb-jar.xml? Or can I make the needed changes there as well?

Comment: @Deery yes, you will find ListenerPorts configuration in traditional WAS console